# How can I use one color gradient for my Google Sheet Charts?

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization

I would like to use one color gradient (e.g. orange) across all values and the color intensify based on higher value.

Please see a traffic chart below. At the moment each traffic value has a different color. I know that I can use conditional formatting but there is a similar workaround for charts?

[image: chart image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

currently (3 Oct, 2022), there is no such option in google sheets charts that would account for the intensification of values group-wise resetting with each next group